# How do I define setParamFile using the MSDeploy API

Tags: powershell, msdeploy

How do I define the -setParamFile parameter from MSDeploy.exe using the MSDeploy API?

I'm trying to write the equivalent of the following in powerShell:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="c:\MyZip.zip" -dest:auto -setParamFile="c:\StagingParameters.xml"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Deployment")
$destBaseOptions   = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentBaseOptions
$syncOptions       = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncOptions
$deploymentObject = [Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager]::CreateObject("package","C:\MyZip.zip")

#TODO -setParamFile="c:\StagingParameters.xml"

$deploymentObject.SyncTo("auto","",$destBaseOptions,$syncOptions);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gotta love reflector!

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Deployment")
$destBaseOptions   = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentBaseOptions
$syncOptions       = new-object Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncOptions
$deploymentObject = [Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager]::CreateObject("package","C:\MyZip.zip")

#-setParamFile
$deploymentObject.SyncParameters.Load("c:\StagingParameters.xml");

$deploymentObject.SyncTo("auto","",$destBaseOptions,$syncOptions);
```